# Часть речи, развивавшаяся позже других

Tags: части-речи

Эта часть речи развилась позже других частей на основе одной из них.

Какие формы послужили основой для развития в русском языке части речи, к которой относится выделенное слово:

> "И всегда, всегда распахнут
>
> Ворот куртки голубой,
>
> И рыбачки только ахнут,
>
> ***ЗАКРАСНЕВШИСЬ*** пред тобой"
>
> (Ахматова)

- краткое причастие
- глагол в прошедшем времени
- наречие
- инфинитив глагола
- полное причастие
- глагол в настоящем времени

Answer (score 1):

Исторически исходной для деепричастий является краткая форма причастий.

Подробнее об этом можете прочитать здесь:[Деепричастие. Русская корпусная грамматика](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Серж, Благодарю!

Comment: Вы имели ввиду краткое причастие?

Comment: То было сказано Сержу. А я имела ввиду, что не могу определить от чего образованно. Я прекрасно понимаю, что это деепричастие - вопрос "что сделавши?". Проблема в том - от чего образованно.

Comment: А вы как думаете от чего образованно?

Comment: Ну да, он прав, раньше, в прошлые века, в основном употребляли краткие причастия, а может даже полных вообще не было. Так что от них пошли и полные причастия, и деепричастия вроде тоже. PS. *Образовано* пишется с одной Н, а *иметь в виду* — раздельно. Написал бы личным сообщением, только вроде тут нет такой возможности, нет?

Comment: Да, вы правы, тут такое возможности нет.

Comment: *Поражена вашей внимательностью. Обязательно скажу своей клавиатуре, чтобы не залипала.

Comment: Будет Вам прикалываться. ;)

Comment: Анастасия9А, я обновил ответ.